When does the Confusion effect from a Spectator end?
In tonight's session, the warlock got hit with a Confusion Ray from a Spectator and failed her save.  I am not sure when the Confusion effect ends.  The ray, in its entirety, says:

Confusion Ray. The target must succeed on a DC 13 Wisdom saving throw, or it can’t take reactions until the end of its next turn. On its turn, the target can’t move, and it uses its action to make a melee or ranged attack against a randomly determined creature within range. If the target can’t attack, it does nothing on its turn.

As written, after a failed save, the confusion never ends.  Since that is clearly unreasonable, does it last "until the end of its [the target's] next turn" and then go away like the target's inability to use reactions, or does the target get to repeat the save at the end of their next turn, as they are explicitly permitted to do with the Paralyzing Ray and Fear Ray?

“Its next turn” and “its turn” are the same turn.
Since “you are confused forever” is the wrong reading, for obvious reasons, it seems to me to be a pretty straightforward reading to interpret “its turn” to be the same turn referred to in the previous sentence. Sure, it’s ambiguous if you ignore the first sentence. But that isn’t how we read anything. The first sentence of the ability specifies the target’s next turn, and the second sentence mentions the target’s turn without specifying further, so naturally, these are the same turn.

I hadn't considered that.  Seems like it could have been written "On that turn, the target can't..." to make it more clear.  Now that I have something to search for though, I note that this interpretation would also work for the confusion effect generated by a gibbering mouther and an umber hulk.  This answer would be stronger if it referenced those as support.

The confusion effect ends with the target's next turn
The ability does not say anywhere that the target suffers a confused condition. It just says

the target cannot take reactions until the end of its next turn
on its turn, the target can’t move, and it uses its action to make a melee or ranged attack against a randomly determined creature within range. If the target can’t attack, it does nothing on its turn.

"Its turn" is a single turn, not "its turns", which reasonably can only be its next turn, not some random, other turn. It would be better if the effect specified that it is the next turn, but it is pretty clear from the context.
You can also compare this with some of the other rays — those that run longer than a turn explicitly tell you to re-save, e.g. the Paralyzing Ray says:

The target can repeat the saving throw at the end of each of its turns, ending the effect on itself on a success.

The confusing ray would need such language to be consistent, if it was intended to work that way.

This tripped me up in my last game. I finally came to this same conclusion, based on the "end of it's next turn" text, but it took me a minute :-)
